# Django REST framework: deserializing foreign key fails (many-to-many)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, deserialization

I have the following model:

models.py:

```
class Host(models.Model):
    serialnr = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ...some other fields...

class Event(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    hosts = models.ManyToManyField(Host, through='EventHost')
    ...some other fields...

class EventHost(models.Model):
    serialnr = models.ForeignKey(Host, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...some other fields...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("serialnr", "event")
```

serializers.py:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = '__all__'

class HostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Host
        fields = '__all__'

class EventHostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event =  EventSerializer(read_only=True)
    serialnr = HostSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = EventHost
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Event.objects.order_by('-date')
    serializer_class = EventSerializer

class HostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Host.objects.order_by('-serialnr')
    serializer_class = HostSerializer

class EventHostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = EventHost.objects.order_by('-start_date')
    serializer_class = EventHostSerializer
```

I'm sending the following JSON with HTTP POST:

```
{event: {id: 4}, serialnr: {serialnr: 1234}, other_filed: 20}
```

but it's not event_id and serialnr_id are not deserialized as seen in the log:

```
psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "event_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (12, 20, null, null).
```

I can read the data with HTTP GET but can't write with POST. How should I construct proper serializer to make it work?

Also when I tried to send JSON like below it fails:

```
{event_id: 4, serialnr_id: 1234, other_filed: 20}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `event` and `serialnr` are ForeignKeys on `EventHost` you need to send data that already exists, so I suggest using `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` in this way you get validation if you send an id that does not exists in your database.

You will need to send data like this:
`{event: 4, serialnr: 1234, other_filed: 20}`

and change your serializer to this:

```
from rest_framework.relations import PrimaryKeyRelatedField


class EventHostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Event.objects.all())
    serialnr = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Host.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = EventHost
        fields = '__all__'

    # add this(if needed) to get event/serialnr representation instead of primary keys 
    # might be usefull for you when you retrieve the object back (in list/retrieve operations)
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        ret['event'] = EventSerializer(context=self.context).to_representation(instance.event)
        ret['serialnr'] = HostSerializer(context=self.context).to_representation(instance.serialnr)
        return ret
```

Later edit:

I found out that there is a library called django-extra-fields that does this in much nicer way.

https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields#presentableprimarykeyrelatedfield

```
from drf_extra_fields.relations import PresentablePrimaryKeyRelatedField


class EventHostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event = PresentablePrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Event.objects.all(), presentation_serializer=EventSerializer
    )
    serialnr = PresentablePrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Host.objects.all(), presentation_serializer=HostSerializer
    )

    class Meta:
        model = EventHost
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are making the `EventSerializer` and `HostSerializer`,
serializer the passed values as `read_only` which means they only work when there is a `retrieve` action, not a `create`

What will solve this is just remove the `read_only` kwarg from your `EventHostSerializer`

like the following:

```
class EventHostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event =  EventSerializer() #read_only=True)
    serialnr = HostSerializer() #read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = EventHost
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I've already tried that but I get: Bad Request: /api/v1/eventhosts/
[06/Feb/2020 09:45:17] "POST /api/v1/eventhosts/ HTTP/1.1" 400 166 . Is there a way to trace what is wrong with my request? What should be the proper JSON format I sent with HTTP POST nested or flattened?

Answer (score 0):

I've removed **read_only=True** parameters from **EventSerializer** and **HostSerializer** and turned on debug to see what is wrong and now what my HTTP POST request does it tries to create new host and new event. That is not what I need. I need just to reference to event and to host to create new entry in the eventhost table.

Just to make note. When I add new eventhost instance with django shell it works:

```
>>> from myapp.models import Host, Event, EventHost
>>> from myapp.serializers import HostSerializer, EventSerializer, EventHostSerializer
myeventhost = EventHost.objects.create(event_id=4, serialnr_id=1234, otherparam=20)
>>> serializedmyeventhost = EventHostSerializer(myeventhost)
>>> serializedmyeventhost.data
{'id': 29, 'event': OrderedDict([('id', 4), ...etc
```